# Detect end of scroll position of a browser control in Windows Phone 8

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-8

i want to fire and event whenever user has scrolled till the end of the page in webbrowser in the web-browser component tool 
here is my code to display webpage in webbrowser component

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FFF4F4F4">
    <phone:WebBrowser  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="wb" Width="480" IsScriptEnabled="True" Height="800" LoadCompleted="wb_LoadCompleted"/>

</Grid>
```

so here i want to detect if the user has scrolled till the end of page and than raise one event

Comment: Rather than detecting end of browser control, why not use javascipt to do it within the control itself and then fire an event.

Comment: how to do that? @Saksham

Comment: Search google for "javascript jquery detect end of page" and for the integration part, search "windows phone communicate with javascript"